# Install font awesome 5 with npm for scss usage

Tags: javascript, npm, sass, font-awesome

like title says, I can not install font awesome 5 with npm for scss purposes.

### Trying to install version 5

Accoring to https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/use-with-node-js

`npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome`

Looking through the installation in node_modules I see no scss file to hook up to. I tried including the styles.css file in my app.scss file but that did not work.

### My setup for version 4:

package.json
`"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",`

app.scss
`@import "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";`

Usage
`<i className="fa fa-save icon controlItem"></i>`

Easy as pie. How can I achieve this with version 5?? Am I using the wrong package?

---

## UPDATE

Apparently, just using @fortawesome/fontawesome is not eanough. The packages have been split up so you also have to select
`npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-regular`

Still I have no success importing it

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
npm install --save-dev @fortawesome/fontawesome
npm install --save-dev @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons
npm install --save-dev @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm install --save-dev @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons
```

In your `app.js` or equivalent Javascript file,

```
import fontawesome from '@fortawesome/fontawesome'
import regular from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'
import solid from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import brands from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'

fontawesome.library.add(regular)
fontawesome.library.add(solid)
fontawesome.library.add(brands)
```

For usage, there are slight changes to the way the class names are being used. Please refer to the icons on Fontawesome site for the "full" class names.

Example

```
<i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
```

---

Although the idea of adding all the 3 variants of fonts into the project seems to be a convenient thing, do beware that this will slow performance when building/compiling your project. Thus, it is highly recommended that you add the fonts you need instead of everything.

Comment: I was confused like OP and have gotten to the point where I have successfully imported Font Awesome 5 like in your example. Now I have a question that maybe you know the answer to: when compiling my `app.js` (using Laravel Mix/webpack) the output file is ~2 MB! I'm only importing one Font Awesome icon set (`fontawesome-pro-regular`) and adding it to `fontawesome.library` in my `app.js`. Since they state [here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/use-with-node-js#using-the-library) that the `fontawesome.library` feature is for explicitly not importing all icons, why does the file become so big?

Comment: Sorry, I am not too sure about this. You have to check with the Font Awesome team. They are in the best position to explain that.

Comment: @Flux I recently just got into the same problem as you. The compilation time took really long to build using webpack

Comment: awesome! no need to import css or scss files anymore +1

Comment: these packages are deprecated. Change to: 
@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons
@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons
@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons

Answer (score 18):

Somehow including fonts in javascript doesn't feel right to me, it's a font and it should belong in css, so here is how to install it using scss:

1. `npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`
2. add `@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css'` in your app.scss file
3. now include app.css to your head and tadaa done

Comment: ... and update the path, depending on your actual setup. ~@fortawesome did not work for me (in a legacy gulp setup for fractal.build design system where we might have 0% JavaScript, otherwise SVG icons are a good idea for page speed optimization). Your answer pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Add the package;

```
npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

and add the scss files in your app.scss;

```
$fa-font-path: "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts";

@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular.scss";
```

then refer the icon in your html files;

```
<i class="far fa-save"></i>
```

.

Answer (score 2):

In case if you'd like to extract all the Font Awesome specific Javascript files to the `vendor.js` using Laravel Mix, you'll need to only extract the packages to the `extract()` method as an array. You won't even need to use the `fontawesome.library.add()` method to add support for the fonts. This will help you to manage the vendor specific file cache in future.

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .extract([
        '@fortawesome/fontawesome',
        '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands',
        '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-regular',
        '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid',
        '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-webfonts'
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of FontAwesome 5 is that they use javascript to add inline SVGs to the DOM.

Take a look at this article: [SVG with JS](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js)

Rather than compiling an scss file, you just need to include this javascipt one: `fontawesome-all.js`, any icons you add to your HTML should then be converted to SVGs automatically.

Comment: Thanks, though there is no fontawesome-all.js in my 5.0.8 - eqvivalent to npm version 1.1.4). I would prefer not to pull it in manually or using url..