# Replacing external css library file with a locally-stored version

Tags: css, angular, font-awesome

I have a css library that I import directly in my main css file like this :

```
@import url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css);
```

I want to store it locally in my project and import it from its folder

I have tried downloading the file and storing it in my `assets/css/` directory then adding the path in `angular.json` like  this:

```
"styles": [
  "src/styles.css",
  "src/assets/css/all.min.css"
],
```

But after `ng build` (it prints all the css file then clear the terminal then no error) then I launch `ng serve` but I get `Failed to compile`

How to do this the most clean way? (without installing unneeded files)

Comment: @FIL and it's not elegant to make edits only to earn reputation. Consider answering questions instead. As for the OP, please explain **in details** your issue, as adding a CSS file to your build probably isn't the issue there.

Comment: Then why are you upset about the guy making his own edit ?

Comment: sorry I rejected your style change because you had deleted one sentence which you should not. I have seen what you would like me to improve, so I re-edited for you. I didn't know you can earn something with this I would've been more fair, I am sorry if it seem rude. @trichetriche thank you for the clarification (i am a girl btw)

Comment: @Takichiii that's ok. I saw that I removed too much by mistake and I tried to re-edit but you were faster ;) Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to download just the all.min.css, it won't work. The font-awesome css package you were importing directly, makes reference to/ depends on other online packages (e.g. sprites and webfonts). My solution would be to use an [npm package of font-awesome](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers), or get it from [github](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome).

Copied from the all.css:

```
.fab {
  src: url("../webfonts/fa-regular-400.eot");
  src: url("../webfonts/fa-regular-400.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff") format("woff"), url("../webfonts/fa-regular-400.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../webfonts/fa-regular-400.svg#fontawesome") format("svg"); }
```

Comment: Maybe you should upload a piece of code showing that this file depends on other files, because right now it seems like you assume it. But upvote for the dependency idea !

Comment: Thank you, I don't understand how to do it. Should I install all `font-awesome` (`npm install font-awesome`) and what to do next? Thank you

Comment: I have downloaded from the git the folder webfonts and put it in assets, and I copied your code snippet and adapted the path to webfonts folder in the project. It still retrieves give me an error at the build : `ERROR in multi ./src/styles.css ./assets/css/all.min.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '`

Comment: This answer on stack overflow should be helpful: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49304017/install-font-awesome-5-with-npm-for-scss-usage/49328677  
OR the link below: 
https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/npm/fontawesome-npm-installation-and-setup/

You don't need my code snippet.